# Images replaced or re-uploaded. Approve or reject edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

In [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30887915), the images were replaced with ones that have new URLs. I appreciate that the images were made visible, but from the side by side comparison I hardly have a chance to verify whether the images before and after are identical.

Should the editor keep the original URLs and should I reject? Or doesn't it matter and it's my problem to verify the contents of the image and approve?

Comment: I think reject. Inlining pictures of text is not an improvement.

Comment: As much as I agree that inserting images of text isn't an improvement, I'm curious about what the answer would be for a more general case where the image actually added something useful to the post.

Comment: As for why the URLs changed, I imagine the editor opened the image links, copied the image directly and pasted the copy buffer as a new image in the question. Not everyone knows the markdown syntax for inline images

Comment: @Phil: exactly, that's likely what happened. Should I then cross check the images for equality and approve or should I reject because it makes the approval so hard?

Comment: @BSMP: Edits by non-OPs can hardly "add" something useful. The images were there before and they are there afterward, it's just a matter of formatting, basically. I'm more interested whether the edit should change links or should not.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the link to the image was already there. I’m saying that the answer you got, that the image should be removed, wouldn’t apply if the image was actually useful instead of a screenshot of text. That’s what I meant by the image (not the editor) adding something to the post.